# Internet randomly stops working but WiFi stays connected (doesn't happen when running Windows)

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Asus UX302LG, but when in Ubuntu the internet will randomly stop loading, the WiFi will stay connected. If I disconnect from my router and reconnect it works, but it will randomly stop again. No other device has this problem, and this same device running Windows does not have this problem.

help me to fix this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: that command did not give any output or error, after pressing enter i just got a new command line below it, the same as pressing enter with nothing typed

Comment: Try `lspci -nn | grep Network` then.

Comment: that lead to the same result, no error, just another new command line directly below